# How to remove the short title emplacement from ANTIBES theme in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, titles, presentations, themes

I'm working with the Antibes theme in beamer which gives me the ability to show current section and subsection but also the Shorten title whcich I want to remove and save this space for the rest. I want to save the space which shown in the figure in red.

I googled this for a long time but I still whitout responses ...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Antibes}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

 \author[My Name]{} 
 \institute[Lab Name]{ complete lab name }

 \title[]{Analyse d’images satellitaires } 

 \begin{document}

  {
 \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
 \begin{frame}
 \titlepage
 \end{frame}


 \section{section one}
 \begin{frame}

 \subsection{subsection one}

 \end{frame}


  \section{section two}
  \begin{frame}

   \subsection{subsection two}
  \end{frame}

   }


   }
```

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you add a MWE to give us something to start with?

Comment: I edit the question and add the minimal code that I used

Comment: You should not use `\subsection` inside a frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own headline and exclude the box with the subtitle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

 \author[My Name]{} 
 \institute[Lab Name]{ complete lab name }

 \title[]{Analyse d’images satellitaires } 

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
%      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
%      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
%    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
      \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
          \hskip2pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
          \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
      \else%  
        \hskip6pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
      \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
          \hskip9.4pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
          \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
      \else%  
        \hskip12pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
} 
\makeatother


 \begin{document}

 {
 \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
 \begin{frame}
 \titlepage
 \end{frame}
 }


 \section{section one}
  \subsection{subsection one}
 \begin{frame}



 \end{frame}


  \section{section two}
     \subsection{subsection two}
  \begin{frame}

  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]